# check the page control is checked or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am using the below code to read the page control.Its working fine. I read the specific control but the control is check box, I want to check the checked status of the control. But i can't do this please help me to do this.

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form)
{
  if (!key.StartsWith("win_")) continue; //win_11 is control id
  string str_val = Request.Form[key];
}
```

Request.Form[key] return the value of the control. But i want to check the checked status.

Answer (score 0):

As u said u find the id of checkbox,,,so u can try this...

```
  foreach (string key in Request.Form)
    {
      if (!key.StartsWith("win_")) continue; //win_11 is control id
      CheckBox cb = this.Page.FindControl("key") as CheckBox;
    if(cb.checked==true)
    {
    Your logic
    }
    else
    {
    your logic
    }
    }
```